# Duvida - Site para Dispositivo Móvel

Tags: mobile, layout-responsivo

De que forma posso fazer com que o Servidor Identifica automaticamente que o Usuário esta sendo utilizado por um Dispositivo móvel celular e mandar ele para o um site próprio para mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se for **Node.js** com **Express** (pelo que notei parece que é o que você usa) ou for no front-end pode então usar o:

- https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js/

### Node.js/Express:

Primeiro instale via `npm`:

```
npm install mobile-detect --save
```

Depois no teu projeto faça algo como isto:

```
var MobileDetect = require('mobile-detect');
var md = new MobileDetect(req.headers['user-agent']);

if (md.mobile()) {
    res.redirect('http://mobile.site.com');
} else if (String(req.get('host')).indexOf('mobile.') == 0) {
    //Acaso acessar o site mobile no navegador Desktop ele irá redirecionar para o site normal
    res.redirect('http://www.site.com');
}
```

### Navegador/front-end

Se for usar no navegador pode baixar o `mobile-detect.min.js` ou então usar o CDN, assim:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mobile-detect/1.4.1/mobile-detect.min.js"></script>
```

Deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
<script src="mobile-detect.min.js"></script>
<script>
var md = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);

if (md.mobile()) {
    window.location.replace('http://mobile.site.com');
} else if (window.location.hostname.indexOf('mobile.') == 0) {
    //Acaso acessar o site mobile no navegador Desktop ele irá redirecionar para o site normal
    window.location.replace('http://www.site.com');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado, precisava dessas referências, me ajudo nós 2 modo, Abraços.

Comment: @MarcosGotado por favor marque a pergunta como correta.